# How can I get active rooms list with gloox lib?

Tags: c++, xmpp, multi-user, gloox

I am writing an xmpp-based chat client using gloox 1.0. I can not find out the way to use gloox to get active rooms list on the server (rooms that other users have created). I use openfire as my local server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Disco](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0/classgloox_1_1Disco.html) object, and a custom class that inherits [DiscoHandler](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0-beta7/classgloox_1_1DiscoHandler.html).

To query the list you call [getDiscoItems(muc_server_jid, ...)](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0-beta7/classgloox_1_1Disco.html#a4). Your DiscoHandler should implement [handleDiscoItems()](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0-beta7/classgloox_1_1DiscoHandler.html#a2), which receives a [Disco::Items](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0-beta7/classgloox_1_1Disco_1_1Items.html) object, `items`.

You can use items.itemList() to get a [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) of pointers to [Disco::Item](http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0-beta7/classgloox_1_1Disco_1_1Item.html) objects. For each Disco::Item you can call item.jid() and item.name() to get the address and (optional) name of the room.

Comment: I have my class: ChatBotDiscoHandler_cl: public DiscoHandler implementing handleDiscoItems( const JID& from, const Disco::Items& items, int context );. Then I call m_pClient->disco()->getDiscoItems(m_pClient->jid().server(), EmptyString, new ChatBotDiscoHandler_cl(), 0);. However, when I debug, it does not run into my derived method. Please show me where I am wrong?